# Laravel querying parts of soft deleted model

Tags: laravel

Hello I would like to ask. If I have for example messages from users and some users get soft deleted I would like to be able query some information from the deleted user model for example if I open a message I can see who was the sender even if the user was already deleted.

I know I can do something like:

```
$messages_model -> user() -> withTrashed() -> get()
```

But that returns the whole model, I only want the email.

I tried something like this:

```
$messages_model -> user() -> withTrashed() -> get(['email'])
```

This almost does what I want but the displayed output still contains some leftovers see below:

```
[{"email":"test@test.com"}]
```

I would like to know how to get only test@test.com, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get emails from all users, you need to use `pluck()` instead of `get()`:

```
->pluck('email');
```

If you want to get email of just one user, you can use the `first()` method:

```
->first()->email;
```